# How to keep method calls in base class stick to base class in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance

```
class son extends parent {
    ...
    public function func_name()
    {
        //do some additional stuff here
        ...
        parent:func_name();
    }

}
```

But in `parent` there's another method:

```
class parent {
...
    public another_func()
    {
        $this->func_name();//how to stick to the one in parent here???
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$inst = new son;
$inst->another_func()////how to make the func_name within another_func stick to the one in parent???
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename `parent::func_name` and make it private. Call that function from `parent::another_func` (and possibly from the new implementation of `parent::func_name`).

Comment: So what? My solution does not make `parent::func_name` private. It renames `parent::func_name` and makes that renamed function private. If you really need a public `parent::func_name`, then you are free to implement one, because `parent::func_name` no longer exists because it was renamed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public another_func () {
    if (get_class($this) == 'parent') {
        $this->func_name(); // $this is an instance of parent object
    } else {
        parent::func_name(); // $this is an instance of some child class
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like hardcoding ,is there a more automated solution?

Comment: You would very special thing, so the solution is very custom.
OOP conception not intended to be used this way.
Public methods should be API for outside, not for some internal work.
In your case, you should make the "func_name" private, because it is utility function, not API.

Answer (score 0):

Or wouldn't `ParentClassName::func_name` work?

Comment: No,must be called by instance.

Comment: Reading your comment on this and then the comments you wrote below, it sounds like you're trying to jailbreak and cheat your way out of how OOP structure is designed (it's designed like this on purpose) - I would think it's time to rethink the design of this particular section and go with something different.  Just a thought.  Good luck.